# Can't display Image in created PDF-File

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I'am working with xsl-fo.

To include an image in a PDF-File i have written the following lines:

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="kopf">  <fo:external-graphic src="url('{.//ImagePath}Logo.png')" content-height="1em" content-width="1em" ></fo:static-content>
```

I have also tried with relative and absolute Path, but nothing worked yet. The weird thing is that i do not get any error messages. The PDF-File gets created with all the Data, but it do not display the Image.

What could be the Problem? Can anyone help?

Comment: What does the resulting `fo:external-graphic` look like?

Comment: There is no result. The place where the image should be is empty space. There is nothing.

Comment: Is your markup example from your XSLT or is that your actual XSL-FO?

Comment: I guess, the variable has been incorrectly resolved. What is displayed if you place `<fo:block><xsl:value-of select="{.//ImagePath}"/></fo:block>` ?

Comment: the Path is displayed: C:\Users\Butt\Desktop\Project\Book.Web\images

Comment: It looks like you need a `/` before `Logo.png`. Also, using `.//ImagePath` seems dangerous as it could return more than one `ImagePath`. Maybe you should narrow that down to a more precise path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems that problem is in your url('{.//ImagePath}Logo.png') path, correct it and get the result.